# SQL Server Reporting Services Role Via Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

I am working on a project where I'm creating an installer application to deploy Reporting Services Reports, I have currently got the reports to deploy using an RSS File, but I need to workout how I can assign a user a new role via code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on this [website](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5d3f5ec2-f5cd-4a55-9897-cf97883f2a28/how-to-programmatically-add-new-role-assignments) and used this example from the [Microsoft website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.wssux.reportingserviceswebservice.rsmanagementservice2005.reportingservice2005.createrole.aspx), but it seems its not supported in the Express version